# Unable to set PATH in linux kali

Tags: zsh, kali-linux, path

I've been trying to add a path but I'm unable to do so. I tried adding `PATH="$PATH:/snap/bin"` in `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` but it didn't work. But if I do `source ~/.profile` it works. Is there a way to make it work without running any commands?
I am using version 2021.2

Thanks.

Edit:
I've added `export PATH="$PATH:/snap/bin:" as well. Didn't work.

This is my `.profile`
[image]

My shell is using zsh and not bash if that is relevant.

Comment: If you change your path after you login, you need to "source ~/.bashrc" to update your path if you're using bash.

Comment: It's using zsh. And as I mentioned I already added the path in `.profile`. And it didn't work. Is there some other way to set path for zsh shells?

Comment: You have to export the PATH. Try adding "export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin'" in your ~/.bashrc. For zsh see "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh".

Comment: I've already done that and it didn't work either

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2021.2 release of Kali Linux uses the `zsh` shell by default.  The `zsh` shell does not read `~/.bashrc` nor `~/.profile`.   Instead, it reads `~/.zshrc` for interactive shells and `~/.zprofile` for login shells.

You most likely want to set your `PATH` at the end of one of these two files (the `~/.zprofile` file does not exist in a default Kali installation, but you may create it):

```bsh
path+=( /snap/bin )
```

(the `path` array is tied to the `PATH` scalar variable in `zsh` and adding a path like above would change both).

You may also *change* your default shell to `bash` using the command

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

This changes the login shell from `zsh` to `bash` and this change takes effect the next time you log in.  Doing this means you may continue to modify your shell's behavior by editing `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` in the way that you seem  used to do.

Comment: I created the `.zprofile` like you asked and added the `path+=( /snap/bin )` in it. Logged out and then logged in. And it still isn't working. Any idea why?

Comment: @TheWhiteFang If you log into a graphical environment, the shell in your terminals may not be a login shell. In that case, add the modification to `path` in your `~/.zshrc` file instead.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. Are there more things that I should look into if I want to use zsh shell?

Comment: @TheWhiteFang That the shell is using another set of files from `bash` should get you over the first hurdle at least. The `zsh` has a fair number of more features compared to `bash`, but I won't be trying to summarize them here. See the `zsh` manual and the manuals that this refers you to. Apart from that, search this site if you run into more issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot man.